# Vertical align span inside a div when text in span re-sizes to fill whole div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table with 25 td's. Each td contains the following elements:

```
<td>
  <div>
    <span>
     text
    </span>
  </div>
</td>
```

I also use a script that re-sizes the text inside the span to fill the whole div,
so a longer text will result in a smaller font size.

Now i'm trying to align the text vertically in the center of the div with no success (whole day). I included [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JucD7/) page with the source code.

Please help me figure out what is wrong here.

Comment: ur solution is "line-height"..

Comment: @BerkerYüceer tried that. breaks the height of the div when used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just do

```
td {
    vertical-align: middle !important;

}

td div {
    display: inline !important
}
```

I don't know if important is needed, I just put on the general styles to override whatever you had

http://jsfiddle.net/JucD7/6/

I tested in FF but I don't see why this would not work in other browsers

Updated

updated fiddle, you jsut all resize on the TD

```
$('td').textfill({ maxFontPixels: 26 });
```

Comment: as you can see it brakes the re-sizing

Comment: @Tom sorry attached your original fiddle, see new fiddle in answer. vertical aligning inside of a table cell is made easy since you can put valign attribute on the td as long as everything inside is inline. What I did is basically the same thing but easier than other solutions and should be the correct way to go about this

Comment: i saw that, i edited my own fiddle with your suggestion. Check what happened to the text size - it is small and doesn't fill the whole outer div

Comment: @Tom like this $('td').textfill({ maxFontPixels: 26 }); 
http://jsfiddle.net/JucD7/6/

Comment: Worked really well and learned another thing today. Great work and thanks for the effort Huangism!

Answer (score 2):

Is this: http://jsfiddle.net/JucD7/3/ Any good for you??

Comment: yes! i see you changed the top position after the resize. what else was changed?

Comment: @Tom Position:relative on your spans

Comment: vertical align should be used, anything else is just too much over thinking

Comment: @Huangism it brakes the re-sizing of the text

Comment: @Tom see my updates, there is always a way, you simply call resize on the td

Comment: @Huangism 's solution is a better one.

Comment: @urbananimal the only thing that's good about tables is it is easy to vertical align things

Comment: @Huangism give me a minute to check things

Comment: @Tom I only did this in FF but vertical-align should work the same for all browsers for tables at least. I am on a mac, so might wanna test IE

Comment: when its about `position:relative;` IE should act as same. +1 good catch there.

Answer (score 0):

try this [demo](http://jsbin.com/ibemuy/1/edit)

```
td {width: 75px!important;
max-width: 75px!important;
overflow: hidden;
height: 75px!important;
max-height: 75px!important;
}
span {display:block;  text-align:center;}
```

Comment: The text-re-sizing doesn't work when i add the display:block. Please view the jsfiddle link above

Comment: i cant access jsfiddle can you please create the came demo on jsbin